# Black and white queens on an 8x8 chessboard

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, chess, checkerboard

What is the largest number of queens that can be placed on a regular $8\times8$ chessboard, if the following rules are met:

> 1. A queen can be either black or white, and there can be unequal numbers of each type.
> 2. A queen must *not* be threatened by other queens of the **same** color.
> 3. Queens threaten all squares in the same row, column, or diagonal (as in chess). Also, threats are blocked by other queens.

Bonus:

> Would this number change if rule 1 was changed to enforce equal numbers of black and white queens?

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/queens-on-a-board-with-two-players

Comment: Threats are blocked by the other color(s). So, yes.

Comment: The conventional meaning of *threaten* is that you can only threaten a man of the other colour. It would confuse chess players less to make rule 2 *"No queen may **protect** another queen of the same colour"*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll guess

> **32 queens**.
>
>  Every other row is filled with alternating queens. Starting queens on each filled row alternate.
>
>   `W B W B W B W B`
>   `- - - - - - - -`
>   `B W B W B W B W`
>   `- - - - - - - -`
>   `W B W B W B W B`
>   `- - - - - - - -`
>   `B W B W B W B W`

I think this is ideal, since for a single queen, cutting off all lines of sight would require:

> `B - B - B`
>  `- - - - -`
>  `- B W B -`
>  `- - - - -`
>  `B - B - B`
>
>  Filling white queens into the spaces and repeating the pattern gives us the 32 solution.

Comment: If you divide the board into 16 2x2 blocks, no block can have more than one queen of each color.

Comment: Are you sure that opposite queens block the threat?

Comment: With his comment of "as in chess", I read it as "the queen needs a direct path".

Comment: @Etoplay If opposite queens didn't block each other, the question would only be asking for two eight-queens solutions that don't share a square.

Comment: @Etoplay @f - Clarified, they do block.

Comment: Arent all the queens threatened diagonally by queens of the same color?

Comment: @Bishop No, since there is an empty row between each row of queens. Same colored queens are a knight's move away from each other.

Comment: Looks optimal, I would accept it :)