# Let's revisit this later (a two player knight's game)

Tags: mathematics, game, checkerboard, knight-moves

Alice and Bob play a game on  the following irregular chessboard. (Note the blacked out squares are not legal moves.)

[image: The game board.]

- Alice starts the game by placing a knight on any square she chooses.
- They then take turns, starting with Bob, moving the knight as a knight moves in chess.
- Immediately reversing the previous move is not allowed.  That is, if one player moves the knight from square $x$ to square $y$, the next player is not allowed to move to square $x$ during the immediate next turn.
- The winner is the first player to move to a square that has been previously occupied sometime during the game.

> Who wins with optimum play and why?

Comment: Do we need to provide a winning strategy or is a proof enough?

Comment: I'm expecting a proof without any specific winning strategy.

Comment: So I guess proving that a) no draw is possible and b) every possible winning strategy for Bob can be mimicked by Alice (or Alice by Bob) would do?

Comment: @VicAche I think the "strategy stealing" argument won't work here, for the same reason as in [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23982/the-knights-game).

Comment: @Sleafar the problem might apply but it may still be easier using that than through brute-force.

Comment: @VicAche Actually it's pretty simple to brute force (especially having a half of the code already). I know the solution but I have (once again) no idea how to explain it.

Comment: @Sleafar I meant hand-bruteforcing. I think it's very uneleguant to use a computer to solve a chess problem.

Comment: There being one W square more than B, it is likely that Alice should win by placing a knight on the W square in the bottom row that completes symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alice wins.

Suppose for contradiction that Bob has a winning strategy.

Claim: If Alice makes the first move on square X, then on the next turn (Bob's), there is exactly one square Y among the neighbors of X on which Bob must make his (first) move to win.

Assuming the claim, for each square X, let f(X) denote the Y as in the claim. Then since there are more W squares than B, there must be two W squares $X_1,X_2$ and a B square Y such that $f(X_1)=f(X_2)=Y$.

Now this gives a strategy for Alice to win by starting at $Y$: if Bob places the knight on a square other than $X_1$, Alice steals Bob's strategy by pretending that Bob already made a move at $X_1$; if Bob places the knight on $X_1$, Alice pretends that the first move was Bob's at $X_2$ and again wins by strategy-stealing.

Proof of the claim:

Suppose for contradiction that Y, Z are two squares both adjacent to X and such that when Alice starts at X, then Bob has a winning strategy by placing his knight at Y or at Z.

Let Alice begin a game by placing the knight at Y.
Now if Bob doesn't place the knight at X, then Alice can pretend to be the second-player where the game began with Bob starting at X; this is a contradiction so Bob must place the knight at X.

But in this case Alice can place the knight on Z and by strategy-stealing again, go on to win. This proves the claim.

Comment: In regards to the proof of claim, what if the winning strategies through Y and Z both end (or can be made to end) with a winning move back to X? Strategy-stealing would just end up with Alice moving to X and Bob winning on Y/Z.

Comment: @Zandar, I don't understand. Since Y and Z are winning for Bob, how can the winning move finish at X?

Comment: I mean the winning move in Bob's original strategy where Alice starts at X. If that winning move is back to X, then it no longer applies if Alice starts at Y or Z instead.

Comment: This is very close!  What I don't understand is, just before you start to prove the claim:   It's true that if Alice starts on $X_2$ that Bob needs to move to $Y$.  You say if the game starts $X_1, Y, X_2$ that Bob would need to move to $Y$ to win.  But now the board is changed so that $Y$ has already been visited, maybe this opens another winning option for Bob?

Comment: @Zandar:  I think the proof of the claim is okay.   Imagine the board is colored like a chessboard with alternating black and white squares.  If Alice starts at X and Bob ends up winning, then the winning move can't be X because (say) X is a black square, and whenever Bob moves he moves to white squares.

Comment: @TylerSeacrest, you are right. I changed Alice's strategy by starting at Y and it seems to work.

Comment: I think you can expand on why "then Alice can pretend to be the second-play where the game began with Bob starting at X" is a contradiction, by saying, "because the result is the same as when Alice make a winning move from X to Y in the previous move, which, being a winning move by stealing Bob's strategy, should end in Alice's win". And perhaps also add what Tyler said in the comment on black-white squares argument. I was initially confused as how is that a contradiction. Otherwise, seems correct to me!

Comment: Assuming winning condition was inverted and there were only tiles a1, b3, c2, d4; no matter which square is picked by A, B has 2 winning moves. Strategy stealing does not work. Besides, in the linked question on another similar game, B wins on 8x8 while A wins on 6x6. So, I don't think this really proves anything.